# How to turn existing DSL broadband modem to wireless modem

Tags: wireless-networking

I am currently using a Fixed Line linked DSL modem to connect to my laptop. But newly an IPhone and a tablet were added to my family and both needs to connect to wi-fi for network connection at home. Is there any way to convert my existing DSL to wi-fi modem.
I know that we need to buy a wi-fi enabled modem and connect to existing connection will
server the purpose. Correct me if I am wrong and suggest me some good 'secured' options as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will either need to buy a WiFi enabled modem, or buy a Wireless router, and connect it to your modem.  Easier to do the first, I think.

You'll need to select an encryption method for use over WiFi.  Go with WPA or WPA2 if at all possible, since WEP is relatively easy to crack.

Comment: oh yes thax!!!!BTW which one is costlier modem or router